# Enabling virtualization in Docker container for Android emulator in a cloud server

Tags: android, docker, docker-compose, emulation, virtualization

I am developing a management application that automates specific tasks. Some of these tasks require interacting with an external application for which we lack ownership and a public API. To overcome this limitation, I have set up an Express server using WebdriverIO to automate actions within an Android simulator. The simulator is launched using AVD Manager and Android Studio's emulator. For deployment, we have chosen to utilize Docker and deploy the containers on a cloud server.

I have successfully configured the container to include the Express server, Appium, the WebdriverIO Android simulator, and the required binaries for device actions. However, when I run the container, I encounter the following error:

```bash
✔ Container android  Recreated                                            0.1s
Attaching to android
android  | INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
android  | INFO    | Found systemPath /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86_64/
android  | WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
android  | WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /root/.android/avd/test.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
android  | ERROR   | x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
android  | CPU acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded
android  | More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
android  | https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
android  | General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
android  | INFO    | Crashreporting disabled, not reporting crashes.
android  | INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
android exited with code 1
```

It appears that I need to enable virtualization within the container. Is there an alternative method to enable virtualization in the Docker container while utilizing the host's virtualization capabilities? I want to ensure smooth execution of the Android emulator within the Docker environment. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Docker Compose (docker-compose.yml):

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    # rest:
    # ...
    # appium:
    # ...

    android:
        container_name: android
        privileged: true
        env_file: .env
        image: android
        command: opt/android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd test -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-window -no-audio -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile.android
            target: android
```

And mi dockerfile.android

```yaml
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS android

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget unzip openjdk-8-jdk-headless qemu-kvm \
    libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN adduser `id -un` libvirt
RUN adduser `id -un` kvm

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip && \
    unzip sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -d /opt/android-sdk-linux && \
    rm sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip

ENV ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses && \
    sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-30" "emulator" "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"

RUN echo "no" | avdmanager create avd --force --name test --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64" --device "pixel" --tag "google_apis"

CMD ["opt/android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator", "-avd", "test", "-netdelay", "none", "-netspeed", "full", "-no-window"]
```

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a _process_ in a restricted environment; you can't "enable virtualization" in a process.  If you're running a VM you usually need to launch it from the host, not from within a container or another VM.

Comment: So what dou yo recommend? To not use compose and only use docker? I tried already and i've same output